# Javascript - OOP reference loop

Tags: javascript, oop

I trying to create Object-"Room" that have another objects-"Items".
I want that every "Item" will have a reference to "Room".

I just want to know what is the "Room" of some "Item"...

Here is the problem :

```js
// Creating Room Class
function Room(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.items = [];
};

// function that creates item in a Room
Room.prototype.addItem = function(name){
    var newItem = new Item(name, this);
    this.items.push(newItem);
}

// Creating Items Class
function Item( name, room ){
    this.name = name;
    this.parentRoom = room; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
    // I need reference to my Room Class
};


// Lets create a Room
var myRoom = new Room('MyRoom');

// And lets add some items
myRoom.addItem("chair");
myRoom.addItem("bed");
myRoom.addItem("computer");

// Result -> you can see endless loop of Rooms in th Items
console.log( myRoom );
```

You can see in Inspect element endless loop.

[Screenshot from Inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVttN.png)

Or what is the right way to create this thing? 
I need to use "extends" method for "Item" Class to "Room"?

Comment: what is an endless loop?

Comment: @dm03514 - Check a screenshot

Comment: Just wondering: Your addItem function takes 1 argument, so why do you pass it 2?

Comment: @Danield - My mistake - edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with un-ending object references when you inspect an javascript object. They essentially form a cyclic graph in object references.

However, this means that you get the benefits **AND** shortfalls of cyclic graphs.

When traversing/iterating through the graph, You need to be careful of infinite loops by keeping track of what objects you've already visited and do **not** visit them more than once. (i.e. by keeping track of a `visited` map)

Comment: So it's OK to use that method? Maybe I need to try some other way?

Comment: How you set up your object is perfectly fine. You just need to be mindful when iterating through the object :)